# Update package summary section in package wiki

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to update some information in "Package Summary" section on my wiki page. I already changed the information in package.xml but anything happens.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301420/update-package-summary-section-in-package-wiki/) by [ricardoej](https://answers.ros.org/users/13141/ricardoej/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2018-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your package is actually in Hydro (as your tags seem to show), then it won't get updated -- because there is no longer a build farm running for Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2018-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ricardoej](https://answers.ros.org/users/13141/ricardoej/) on 2018-08-23**:
Thanks! In a more recent version, just need to update the package.xml file in git repository?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2018-08-24**:
Yes, I'm not sure how often the indexer runs, so it might be a few days, but it will pick up changes for any still-supported distribution.